# AWS AppSync trigger lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync

I have currently created a .net backend with HotChocolate to create GraphQL queries. The reason for that is that I feel more in control when using API Gateway.

However, I have noticed that AppSync is maybe the preferred way of connecting DynamoDB with GraphQL.

But, I cannot find any good answers on how to trigger other lambdas when e.g. updating a user. Say I want to update a user, when the user is updated, I want to trigger a Lambda that notifies all the users on a certain list that the user is updated. My problem is more complex than that, but you get the point.

Another thing is authorization. It seems easier to authorize through AppSync rather than in either API Gateway or directly in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot find any good answers on how to trigger other lambdas when e.g. updating a user.

Defining your Appsync resolvers as [Direct Lambda Resolvers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-direct-lambda/) gives you the opportunity to perform work as part of the GraphQL request-response cycle.  Appsync invokes your lambda with the `updateUser` mutation request context and parameters. In addition to returning the requested type back to Appsync, your lambda can perform arbitrary work or trigger other work.

> I have noticed that AppSync is maybe the preferred way of connecting DynamoDB with GraphQL

AppSync is AWS's managed GraphQL service.

> It seems easier to authorize through AppSync rather than in either API Gateway or directly in the backend

AppSync has [multiple integrated auth options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html), supporting a range of simple and fine-grained access control patterns.

Comment: I have a subscriber which listens to a mutation, I have also added a lambda resolver for the subscriber. E.g: On a update, I want the subscriber to trigger the lambda. However, this does not work. Any clues?

Comment: @newbie Could be any number of things, including permissions.  In any case, I believe its more logical to put the direct lambda resolver on your mutation, not the subscription.  Also see [this article](https://dev.to/aws-builders/lessons-learned-aws-appsync-subscriptions-jek) about AppSync subscriptions, especially point #5.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. But do you know anything about @aws_oidc authorization when using mutations

Comment: @newbie Not much.  You should ask a new question to address that topic.